# Best DB for datalogging

Tags: mongodb, redis, couchdb, database

I have a lot of logged data stored into a database by a data logger. Basically i have a lot of rows with a timestamp and some values. I want to store this data into a db that has performance and can scale on a multi node structure to support fault tolerance behaviour (and balance requests). Typically i use MySQL but i find its scalability not simple for this type of application. This time, i want offer other db scenarios.
So: Mongo, Redis, Couchdb?
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hard question to answer and not something we can really give answers to on SO.

**Redis** is quick for getting the data in, but you can not query on the values of the keys so searching would be harder.

**MongoDB & CouchDB** would both work well as they are document stores and can be used to store any format for the logs.

There are other options. I know **Cassandra** is used a lot for this task, but there is also **ElasticSearch** as in (ElasticSearch, Log Stash, Kibana) which is a great solution for central logging.

In the end it probably down to what you want to do with the data.

Comment: I'm directed for a redis + MySql approach, so i can gather lot of data and use redis as a cache, then mysql for the application. Your answer cleared some doubts, thanks

Comment: So long as it can keep up with the amount of data you are inserting & allows you to query the data in the ways the you want, it shouldn't matter to much. What ever your most comfortable administering.